# count the pinnumber in visible rect of mkmapkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I  have created one Google map view using MK Mapkit and i have annotated pins on different locations now i want to calculate number of pins on visible rect on map view also on when i zoom the map view?

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `MKMapView` `annotationsInMapRect:` method will give you the set of annotations in a given map rect.

To get the ones currently visible, pass it the map view's `visibleMapRect` property.

To detect what annotations are visible after a zoom in, zoom out, or pan, call that method in the `regionDidChangeAnimated` delegate method:

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSSet *annSet = [mapView annotationsInMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect];
    NSLog(@"regionDidChangeAnimated: annSet count = %d", annSet.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. of pin can be counted by  the following delegate method

-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView1 viewForAnnotation:(id )annotation

{

Count ++
   NSLog(@"Count : %d", count);

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a ViewController with mapView as a subview.

```
- (void)someMethod
{
    NSArray *visibleAnnotations = [[self.mapView annotationsInMapRect:self.mapView.visibleMapRect] allObjects];
    NSUInteger VisibleAnnotationCounts = visibleAnnotations.count;
...
}
```

You can also add to a proper MKMapView Delegate Method

```
{
...
    NSArray *visibleAnnotations = [[mapView annotationsInMapRect:mapView.visibleMapRect] allObjects];
    NSUInteger VisibleAnnotationCounts = visibleAnnotations.count;
...
}
```