# mapView:didAddAnnotationViews doesn't always pick up the annotations

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I have placed a number of annotations on a map, and when the user touches the location button, the view zooms in on the user location, which contains a number of annotations.

`mapView:didAddAnnotationViews` is called and should add all the annotations inside the current view into an NSArray.

Sometimes it adds all the annotations without any problems, but other times, it only adds the one annotation which is the user location (blue dot).

I suspect it may have to do with being called before the map has finished rendering, but i'm not sure.

Not sure if it's possible to link the function `mapViewDidFinishRenderingMap` to `didAddAnnotationViews` so that it will only load once the view has been completed loading (including all the annotations).

Would appreciate any advice regarding this, as I am relatively new to Swift.

Here's some of my code. I've got a timer that runs every second and prints out the size of the array in the console.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "update", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

func mapView (mapView: MKMapView!, didAddAnnotationViews views: [AnyObject]!) {

    pinannotationarray = views

}   

func update() {

    if (pinannotationarray != nil && locationManager.location != nil)
     {
       println("pinannotationarray size \(pinannotationarray.count)")
     }
}
```

** Revised Code **

```
var annSet: AnyObject!

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {

annSet = mapView.annotationsInMapRect(mapView.visibleMapRect)
println("regionDidChangeAnimate: annSet count = \(annSet.count)")

for (var i = 0; i < annSet.count; i++)
    {
    pinannotation = annSet.allObjects[i].annotation as? MyAnnotation

    //fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value       
    println(pinannotation.title)
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the relevant code?  It's not clear what you're trying to do or what the problem is.

Comment: Instead of posting long code in comments, Edit your question and add it there. The delegate method can be called multiple times as annotations are being added or as they come into view while the map is zooming or panning.  What is the goal you are trying to achieve by getting the list of annotations?  How and where is pinannotationarray used?  Add this information to the question (break it up into logical paragraphs instead of a wall of text).

Comment: Thanks Anna, as you can see this is my first time using stackoverflow, and I have no idea how it works. 

Basically, I would like to compare the distance between my current location with all the annotations that are in the current view. Is there a way to only have the delegate called after the screen is completely finished rendering?

Comment: The timer is most likely not the right approach here.  Instead of didAddAnnotationViews, try the regionDidChangeAnimated delegate method.  There, you can get an NSSet of the visible annotations using annotationsInMapRect.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8846927/count-the-pinnumber-in-visible-rect-of-mkmapkit

Comment: Thanks Anna, I have tried using the regionDidChangeAnimated method, and am able to count the number of visible annotations using annSet.count, however when trying to cast annSet as a custom MKPointAnnotation Class (MyAnnotation), I get nil values. Please see updated code above.

Comment: Any ideas, why I'm getting a nil value, even though println(annSet.count) is showing a number that equates to the number of annotations in the visible map rect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `annotationsInMapRect` method returns an `NSSet` containing the annotation model objects (eg. `MKPointAnnotation`) -- not the views (eg. `MKAnnotationView`).

That also means `annSet.allObjects` will be an `NSArray` containing the annotation model objects.

That means `annSet.allObjects[i].annotation` is invalid and will fail (annotation views have an `annotation` property and not the annotations themselves) which leaves `pinannotation` as `nil` resulting in the crash.

Change the assignment to:

```
pinannotation = annSet.allObjects[i] as? MyAnnotation
println(pinannotation.title)
```

or to be a little safer:

```
if let pa = annSet.allObjects[i] as? MyAnnotation {
    println(pa.title)
}
```

By the way, you don't even need to generate an `NSArray` from the `NSSet`.  You can iterate the `NSSet` directly:

```
for ann in annSet as NSSet {
    if let ma = ann as? MyAnnotation {
        println("ma.title = \(ma.title)")
    }
}
```